# run console commands from PHP

Tags: php, shell, unix

*PHP Version 5.4.6--pl0-gentoo*

While I'm running this code:

```
$command = "/var/www/site/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /var/www/site/pdf_s.html
/var/www/site/test.pdf 2>&1";

passthru($command, $retval);
echo '<br />'.$command.'<br />';
var_dump($retval);
```

mostly I receive error #**127**, ones the output was:

> Loading pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10%
>   [=============================> ] 49%
>   [============================================================] 100%
>   QPainter::begin(): Returned false Error: Unable to write to
>   destination  /var/www/site/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
>   /var/www/site/pdf_s.html /var/www/site/test.pdf 2>&1 int(1)

When I'm setting `$command = '/bin/ls 2>&1';` it works 50/50, sometimes output is how it should be and sometimes it is error #**127** again.

What is the magic? Why sometimes command executes fine and sometimes (mostly) I recieve error #127??
Why do this two commands work perfect in console but not in PHP?

Comment: Maybe because `php` is executed at a different user-level?

Comment: Does the user that PHP is running as (apache?) have write access to `/var/www/site/test.pdf` , given that you have created it from the command-line?

Comment: Are you running this script from the command line or on your web server (via mod_php)?

Comment: @Andrew I'm running this script on my web-server(apache+php) and via command line. In command line it works fine but not in php

Comment: @Yekver Could you try completely stopping Apache Httpd and running something like `ps aux | grep "httpd\|apache"` to ensure it is completely stopped. It sounds to me like one of the workers is running in the wrong environment, or as the wrong user (perhaps a stale worker that didn't stop properly on a previous shutdown).

Comment: @Johnsyweb I'm interested not is there enought writing rights for apache user, but in why mostly I recieve error #127?

Comment: @Yekver, the reason that you receive the error #127 *is* because the apache user does not have write access.

Comment: It can't be true that "it works 50/50, sometimes output is how it should be and sometimes it is error #127 again."  Something is different between the two different ways you're invoking your PHP file.  PHP doesn't play dice with the universe.

Comment: @Andrew if u were right I'll be always recieving error #127, but as I said before, sometimes I recieve another output (like command were executed correctly). So I don't think than wrong rights is the point.

Comment: @AndyLester can't be but it is. If it wasn't I'll solve the problem by myself, that's why I need some help. Thanks. File was modified only like I change one command string to another one and thats all.

Comment: Looks like you are not the only one with this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881315/linux-permissions-issue-when-executing-wkhtmltopdf-amd64