# wkhtmltopdf does not create pdf for Debian

Tags: php, debian, wkhtmltopdf

This is my PHP code which I am using to convert HTML file to pdf and then download pdf file from server.

**wkhtmltopdf**

```
$url = base_url().'invoices/'.$file_name.'.html';                    
exec("wkhtmltopdf-amd64 $url {$file_folder}{$file_name}.pdf");

header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name.pdf");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
$pdfFile = base_url().'invoices/'.$file_name.'.pdf';
readfile($pdfFile);
```

& after execute exec("wkhtmltopdf-amd64 $url {$file_folder}{$file_name}.pdf"); it does not create pdf file in the folder

It is working fine on **Ubuntu** but on **Debian** after download pdf, when open pdf Adob Reader says error please see the image.

I think the issue is due to **exec()** not working in **Debian**...!

[image]

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Debian I needed to install **xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf**

Comment: I have to install xvfb-run but always like this case, can I get spesific solution maybe the configuration or etc, please, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for the path in base_url() is passing correct path during download of the file,
to test that write down the path in browser and check whether it gets downloaded or not

Comment: ulr is pointing correct, sorry one thing more i m using wkhtmltopdf & after execute exec("wkhtmltopdf-amd64 $url {$file_folder}{$file_name}.pdf"); it does not create pdf file in the folder.

Comment: That's what it is happening when there is no file in the or of proper format that error is given and for wkhtmltopdf this may help u [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881315/linux-permissions-issue-when-executing-wkhtmltopdf-amd64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881315/linux-permissions-issue-when-executing-wkhtmltopdf-amd64)